# Load NGRX modules after 'APP_INITIALIZER' finish to load data

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I implement 'APP_INITIALIZER' this in my project and load some data example [here](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER)
and after my data finish to load I want NGTX will load. (The data that return it my env)

after it load I want to init NGRX library.
I need to add it to import appModule (only after APP_INITIALIZER done to load some data).

StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers })
EffectsModule.forRoot([AppEffects])

etc.

How can I implement it?

Comment: Doesn't Angular do it already?

Comment: @FatihErsoy no couse import load when application load.

Comment: What's the objective? Which issues are you trying to fix by delaying loading NGRX?

Comment: @WillAlexander 'APP_INITIALIZER' initial service that load env file and NGRX effect load default env couse he start before APP_INITIALIZER and env finish

Comment: Do you return a Promise or an Observable from your initializer function?

Comment: @WillAlexander Yea. i return promise from that, I don't see returning observable on that situations it possible?, but anyway Store init before and all effect use default env (all application init after yea only store not cosue he on appModule import)

Comment: The initializer can be a promise or and observable https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER. Anyway please elaborate in your question what you want to do exactly

Comment: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/3659
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/931

Maybe these comments can help you.